# Django Loading Wrong Settings Module in Docker

Tags: django, database, gunicorn

I have my Django application configured to use sqlite in the base settings file and  I overwrite the setting in the production and development settings files.

I set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to the correct value in my Dockerfile.

However, when I run it, it uses sqlite as defined in the base settings file.  If I comment it out I it complains about database.ENGINE not being set.

Why is it reading the database configuration from the base.py settings file rather than the other?  I specify the other in the environment variable and it's reading other settings from there but for the database it reads it from the base file.

I'm somewhat confused by this behavior, if anyone could give me some direction towards solving this issue it would be appreciated.

If you need any more information let me know.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
LABEL maintainer xxx@xx.com

ARG requirements=requirements/production.txt
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sasite.settings.production_test

WORKDIR /app

COPY manage.py /app/
COPY requirements/ /app/requirements/ 

RUN pip install -r $requirements

COPY config config
COPY sasite sasite
COPY templates templates
COPY logs logs
COPY scripts scripts

EXPOSE 8001

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "config/gunicorn.conf", "--log-config", "config/logging.conf", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8001", "sasite.wsgi:application"]
```

Comment: Can you paste your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gunicorn might be daemonized, and it might not be inheriting the docker env variable the way you expect.  Fortunately, gunicorn does have a way that you can specify an env value for its workers using the `-e` flag.  So you can just add the following two parameters to your `CMD` array, and it should work:

1. `-e`
2. `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sasite.settings.production_test`

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "config/gunicorn.conf", "--log-config", "config/logging.conf", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8001", "-e", "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sasite.settings.production_test", "sasite.wsgi:application"]
```

Comment: Did not work for me. It's still looking in the default i.e. settings.py for some reason...

Comment: If you want, feel free to post another question and @mention me, and I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Looks like I figured out this step, thanks. In my case I also had to pass all vars one by one with "--build-arg" switch to "docker build"